# postgres: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, postgresql

Given the Postgres query:

```
INSERT INTO net.bgp_communities (comm_name, comm_value) VALUES (%s, %s) ;
```

and the data

```
('blabla', 'target:*:*')
```

the resulted query is (using `mogrify`)

```
INSERT INTO net.bgp_communities (comm_name, comm_value) VALUES ('blabla', 'target:*:*') ;
```

which causes

```
TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)
```

I believe that the error comes from the tuple not having the `,` at the end ? But how can this be resolved ?

**EDIT:**

describing how the query is rendered together with the tuple using psycopg2

```
curs.executemany("""INSERT INTO net.bgp_communities (comm_name, comm_value) VALUES (%s, %s)""", msg)
```

Comment: The trailing `,` at the end of a `tuple` is only required when the tuple only has one element. Eg. `('a',)` is a tuple, `('a')` is not.

Comment: thanks! any idea who to escape given how `psycopg2` renders the query ?

Comment: Please show the exact call to `mogrify` that produces the error.

Comment: @chepner thanks! see `edit`

Comment: At which moment does the `TypeError` happen? May we please see a complete stack trace?

Comment: `executemany` takes a *list* of tuples.

Comment: Note that `executemany` expects an iterable of argument sets - `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sometable (id, somefield) VALUES (%s, %s)", [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')])` should be correct while `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sometable (id, somefield) VALUES (%s, %s)", (1, 'a'))` should be incorrect.

Comment: thank you guys. i had forgotten `executemany` during troubleshooting of a single tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Resolved in comments**:
>   Note that `executemany` expects an iterable of argument sets -
>
> ```
> cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sometable (id, somefield) VALUES (%s, %s)", [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')])
> ```
>
> should be correct , while
>
> ```
> cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sometable (id, somefield) VALUES (%s, %s)", (1, 'a'))
> ```
>
> should be incorrect. – Kendas